# Test react component after state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, mocha.js, enzyme

How can I test the following component?

```
    import React from "react";

    class ModuleLoader extends React.Component {
            state = {
                    Module: null
            };
            componentDidMount() {
                    this.props
                            .Module()
                            .then(loaded => {
                                    this.setState({ Module: loaded.default });
                            })
            }
            render() {
                    if (this.state.error) {
                            return "error";
                    }
                    if (!this.state.Module) {
                            return "loading";
                    }
                    return <this.state.Module {...this.props} />;
            }
    }

    export default ModuleLoader;
```

Prop Module is function that returns promise with dynamic import. When that import is resolved and loaded it returns one react component, that should be stored in state and rendered. So what should a test look like to let component resolve network request load it, display it and after it is rendered check the assertion?

I would expect something to check that state on rendered component changed. But I cannot fund something like that in docs.

I'm using `Meteor`, `Mocha` and `Enzyme`.
If it's not possible to test the component with `Enzyme` I can switch to an alternative.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted to test this component? What problems have you encountered?  For more advice on how to write a good question, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is in proper use of promises and `await`.

```
it('renders', async () => {
  const props = {
    Module: () =>
      Promise.resolve({
        default: () => <span>Im loaded!</span>,
      }),
  };
  const component = mount(<ModuleLoader {...props} />);
  expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  await Promise.resolve(); // tick so promises resolve
  expect(component.update()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/danielhusar/8df72f5677ec69cb9774c1d5c561c56a

Answer (score -1):

Why is it not possible to achieve the behavior you want with enzyme? Does your componentDidMount() not get called with shallow rendering? If so, you could try full rendering (https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme#full-dom-rendering) or else create a helper method that gets called from componentDidMount() but can also be called manually in your unit test. Then after awaiting that method, you can test that the rendered component contains `Module`. So, I think you have two options for how to test this component renders a `Module`.